# Acoustic stud wall - over laminate flooring or not?

Tags: sound-proofing

I have one question for whoever might know a thing or two about sound insulation. I will install a stud wall over the existing brick party wall for sound proofing purposes.

Currently we have laminate flooring over the old floor boards, is it ok to install a stud wall over the laminate, leaving 1cm gap at the bottom for the acoustic sealant, or should I cut the portion of laminate beneath and go with the studs down to the floor boards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laminate flooring should typically not be pinned by cabinetry, walls, etc. It needs to be able to move slightly. I would cut a channel for the new wall plate.

Be aware that many such floors have very hard wear layers. It can be hard on saw blades.

---

Update: I now understand that you're talking about a suspended wall, or perhaps just furring strips on the brick. In that case, it's fine to run the flooring underneath. However, I'm not sure even acoustic caulk is flexible enough to prevent problems. I'd probably use foam rope caulk--something that isn't actually bonded to either the wall plate or the flooring.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it might just tip me towards cutting the laminate; however the laminate would not be "pinned" as the stud wall would stop slightly above it and the gap filled with acoustic glue which is flexible.